# Grabing image SRC attr with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-mobile

it's Jquery Mobile I want to grab an image **src** from rss discription tag,
I want to grab a SRC of image to a variable, I tried many ways but it didn't work for me, that's my code:
I want to add the variable that contains the SRC in this img tag SRC:

```
document.write(
    '<li id="list' + i + '"><img src="**#img**" class="ui-li-thumb"><a href="#article' + i + '" id="link' + i + '">&nbsp;</a></li>'
  );
```

The black text is the variable.
and I tried to grab the img src from a text that starts with img tag and so on:

```
$('#link' + i).text(entry.title);
$('#img' + i).text(entry.content);
```

The image I want to grab is inside: `text(entry.content)`

Answer (score 2):

Get src **attribute** value:

```
var variable = $('#img' + i).attr('src');
```

Set src **attribute** value:

```
$('#img' + i).attr('src', "http://example.com/img.png");
```

Where '#img' + i is a tag  with id img1, img2 etc...
For instance:

```
<img id="img0" />
```

`text` - this is jquery function which will use .innerText/.innerContent inside of it. 
And image with inner text - there is nothing like that. 
`.getElementById` - that is javascript object `window` function to get an element by id. It has nothing common with jQuery object returned by most of jQuery functions (`.text` is one of them)

[jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/) - this is what you MUST read to get an info about what you can do with DOM using jQuery.

Comment: Sorry for posting a similar answer. I was already writing my answer and I didn't realize that you had posted an answer. +1 from me

Comment: Where can I add "text(entry.content)" to grab the image from, In your code?

Comment: Any tag which can contain some other tags inside. According to your code (which is something I do not really understand) it may be something like `$('#link' + i).html(entry.content).find("img").attr("src")` You can't use text in this case as all HTML tags will be shown as a simple text, without producing DOM objects. But `.html` will replace everything inside #link, so maybe you will find more useful `.append` function

Answer (score 2):

You could try the following:

```
<img id="first-image" src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42" />
```

Get the src using:

```
var currentSrc = $("#first-image").attr("src");
```

Modify the src using:

```
$("#first-image").attr("src", "smiley_2.gif");
```